# Joomla 3 component xml install a folder into the root

Tags: xml, joomla, components, directory, joomla3.0

I am creating a Joomla 3.1.x component.

In the components XML, I have:

```
<files folder="site">
```

and

```
<files folder="administrator">
```

I want to install another folder that must go into the root of Joomla.

How do I do this is the xml?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a script.php file.

Firstly, add the following to your xml file:

```
<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```

then add this to your script.php:

```
class com_componentnameInstallerScript
{
      public function install();
          $path = JPATH_SITE . "/folder_name";
          JFolder::create($path, 0755)
      }     
}
```

Don't forget to change `com_componentname` and `folder_name`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an installer script file to override directory creation in normal installer flow from the manifest. See [Joomla documentation here](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a file tag rather than a folder tag. You can put a file anywhere.
You can also package a single file using the file adapter.